# Forward a file data from one Web Api to another Web Api

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I have a winform application from where I am making a call to a webapi which inturns calls another public API on the web.
The winform uploads a file and passes the file to the interim WebAPI which further passes it across to the other public facing API for further processing.

All I do not want to do is persist any data from the file in anyform in my webAPI.
Here is where I have reached so far.
I am using Restsharp to make my calls.

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
            {
                if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                    throw new Exception();

                var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                var file = provider.Contents.First();
                var fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                //Rest call to my Public API
                var publicAPIRsult = Client.CallMYpublicAPI(await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), fileName);

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, publicAPIRsult.Content.ToString());
                return response;

            }
```

Is there a better way to make this call?
The code review feedback that I am getting on this snippet is that it would use in a lot of memory and should pass the data directly to the API call instead of reading it from the response and then passing it across.

Any suggested Improvements ?

Comment: I tried mixing a custom MultipartStreamProvider and a PushStreamContent with very limited success.  

Also had to deal with a custom IHostBufferPolicySelector in order to prevent incoming request content from being buffered (as discussed here: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/).

Still ended up with OutOfMemoryException on relatively small files (200mb), so something's definitely not set up correctly.

Comment: did you solve this issue?